# How to use cakephp 2 with custom database connection and raw queries

Tags: cakephp

I have to work with an Oracle database using the old database driver (ora_logon ) which is not supported by cakephp. I cant use the oci driver instead.

Right now I do the follow:
Every method of every model connects to the database and retrieve data

```
class SomeClass extends Model {
    public function getA(){
        if ($conn=ora_logon("username","password"){
            //make the query
            // retrieve data
            //put data in array and return the array
        }
    }

    public function getB(){
        if ($conn=ora_logon("username","password"){
            //make the query
            // retrieve data
            //put data in array and return the array
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it is not the best way go.
How could I leave cakephp manage opening and closing of the connection to the database and have models only retrieve data? I'm not interested in any database abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you could just make your own OracleBehavior.  Each model could use this behavior, and in it, you can overwrite or extend the Model's find() behavior to build a traditional oracle query and run it (I don't know much about Oracle).

Then, in your Behavior's [beforeFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind) you can open your connection, and in your Behavior's [afterFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind), you can close your database connection.

That way, every time before a query is run, it automatically opens the connection, and every time after a find it closes it.  You can do the same with beforeSave() and afterSave() and beforeDelete() and afterDelete().  (You'll likely want to create a single `connect()` method and `disconnect()` method in the Behavior, so you don't have duplicate code in each beforeX() method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **really** need to extend a Cake Model class?

```
class SomeClass extends Model {
    private $conn;
    public function constructor() {
        parent::constructor();
        $conn = ora_logon("username","password");
        if(!$conn)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public function getA() {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

SomeController:

```
App::uses('SomeClass','Model');

public function action() {
    $data = array();
    $error = null;
    try{
        $myDb = new SomeClass();
        $data = $myDb->getA();
    } catch($e) {
        $error = 'Cannot connect to database';
    }
    $this->set(compact('data', 'error'));
}
```